# Norm of linear transformation on $\mathbb{C}^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations

I am going through Functional analysis of J.Conway. I encountered with next problem (2.1.11) :

> If $A=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\ c&d\end{pmatrix}$, put $\alpha=\sqrt{|a|^2+|b|^2+|c|^2+|d|^2}$ and show that $$||A||=\frac{1}{2}(\alpha^2+\sqrt{\alpha^4-4\delta^2})$$ 
>   where $\delta^2=\det A^\ast A$.

My solution:

$$\begin{align}
||A||^2=\sup_{||x||=1}||Ax||^2&=\sup_{\theta,\varphi,\psi}\Bigg|\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}e^{i\varphi}\cos\theta \\ e^{i\psi}\sin\theta\end{pmatrix}\Bigg|^2\\\
&=\sup_{\theta,\varphi,\psi}\Big( (|a|^2+|c|^2)\cos^2\theta+(|b|^2+|d|^2)\sin^2\theta+\sin 2\theta\times\text{Re}((a\overline{b}+c\overline{d})e^{i(\varphi-\psi)})\Big)\\
&=\sup_\theta\Big( (|a|^2+|c|^2)\cos^2\theta+(|b|^2+|d|^2)\sin^2\theta+\sin 2\theta|a\overline{b}+c\overline{d}|\Big)\\
&=\sup_\theta \Big(|a|^2+|c|^2-(|a|^2+|c|^2-|b|^2-|d|^2)\sin^2\theta+\sin2\theta|a\overline{b}+c\overline{d}|\Big)\\
(\text{symmetrically})&=\sup_\theta \Big(|b|^2+|d|^2+(|a|^2+|c|^2-|b|^2-|d|^2)\cos^2\theta+\sin2\theta|a\overline{b}+c\overline{d}|\Big)\\
\end{align}$$

Therefore by adding two last lines and divide by 2,
$$\begin{align}
||A||^2&=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\alpha^2+\sup_\theta(|a|^2+|c|^2-|b|^2-|d|^2)\cos 2\theta+2\sin2\theta|a\overline{b}+c\overline{d}|\bigg).
\end{align}$$

By taking derivative w.r.t $\theta$ and get a maximal, I have

$$\sup_\theta(|a|^2+|c|^2-|b|^2-|d|^2)\cos 2\theta+2\sin2\theta|a\overline{b}+c\overline{d}|=\sqrt{(|a|^2+|c|^2-|b|^2-|d|^2)^2+4|a\overline{b}+c\overline{d}|^2}.$$

Moreover, calculating $\delta^2$ yeilds :

$$\delta^2=\det A^\ast A=|a|^2|b|^2+|b|^2|c|^2+|c|^2|d|^2-|a\overline{b}+c\overline{d}|^2.$$

Therefore combine everything I have

$$||A||^2=\frac{1}{2}(\alpha^2+\sqrt{\alpha^4-4\delta^2}).\square$$

Questions :

1. In the problem, L.H.S is not squared. Do you think this is typo? Or I missed something?
2. Is there any shorter or elegant way to solve this problem? It seems taking too much calculations. And the $||A||$ is the solution of $$||A||^4-\alpha^2||A||^2+\delta^2=0,$$ but have no idea what is the intuition behind of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know a little bit of linear algebra, the problem might get a little easier:

For a square matrix $A$ (of arbitrary dimension) one can show using singular value decomposition that $\|A\|=\sigma_1(A)$, where $\sigma_1(A)$ is the largest singular value and that the singular values of $A$ are the roots of the eigenvalues of $A^*A$.

Since here $B=A^*A$ is $2\times 2$, the characteristic polynomial is $$p_B(\lambda)=\lambda^2-\text{tr}(B)\lambda+\det (B)=\lambda^2-\alpha^2\lambda+\delta^2$$

so the two eigenvalues of $B$ are

$$\lambda_{1,2}=\frac 12 (\alpha^2\pm\sqrt{\alpha^4-4\delta^2})$$

which then gives

$$\|A\|^2=\sigma_1(A)^2=\lambda_1=\frac 12 (\alpha^2+\sqrt{\alpha^4-4\delta^2})$$

This harmonizes with what you wrote down in 2.: $\|A\|^2$ is a solution of $\lambda^2-\alpha^2\lambda+\delta^2=0$, in fact $\|A\|^2$ is the larger of the two zeros of the characteristic polynomial of $A^*A$.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!